# Regular expression for specific combination of alphabets and numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create regular expression for following type of strings:

> combination of the prefix (XI/ YV/ XD/ YQ/ XZ), numerical digits only, and either no ‘Z’ or a ‘Z’ suffix.

For example, `XD35Z` should pass but `XD01HW` should not pass.

So far I tried following:

- `@"XD\d+Z?"` - `XD35Z` passes but unfortunately it also works for `XD01HW`
- `@"XD\d+$Z"` - `XD01HW` fails which is what I want but `XD35Z` also fails
- I have also tried `@"XD\d{1,}Z"?` but it did not work

I need a single regex which will give me appropriate results for both types of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing the `$` which represents the end of the string in the Regex

It should be : `@"^XD\d+Z?$"` (notice that it appears at the end of the Regex, after the `Z?`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(XI|YV|XD|YQ|XZ){1}\d+Z{0,1}$
```

I'm using quantifying braces to explicitly limit the allowed numbers of each character/group.  And the `^` and `$` anchors make sure that the regex matches only the whole line (string).

Broken into logical pieces this regex checks

- `^(XI|YV|XD|YQ|XZ){1}` Starts with exactly one of the allowed prefixes
- `\d+` Is follow by one or more digits
- `Z{0,1}$` Ends with between 0 and 1 `Z`

Answer (score 0):

The regex following the behaviour you want is:

```
^(XI|YV|XD|YQ|XZ)\d+Z?$
```

Explanation:

> combination of the prefix (XI/ YV/ XD/ YQ/ XZ)

```
^(XI|YV|XD|YQ|XZ)
```

> numerical digits only

```
\d+
```

> ‘Z’ or a ‘Z’ suffix

```
Z?$
```